# Query for Running Total of Growth Per Quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, count, sum

Using SQL Server 2017. The goal is to get a running total of employees hired per quarter. I have the running total figured out (I think), but I'm getting too many results where I need only one result (total) per quarter. Two tables: the main table is the Employee table with the hire date, the EmpGrowth table is below that I'm using to save the data employee table. This result is being used in a line graph with limited space, so having a large number of data points makes the graph too crowded. 1 point for each quarter is needed to keep the graph clean and useable. This will end up in a stored procedure where the project ID will be passed as a variable. How can I get the result I'm looking for?

```
CREATE table EmpGrowth
(
    DID INT NOT NUll IDENTITY, 
    Q NVARCHAR(2) NULL,
    Y NVARCHAR(4) NULL,
    C INT NULL
)

Delete From EmpGrowth


INSERT INTO EmpGrowth
select DATEPART(QUARTER, EmpHireDate)as 'Q', DATEPART(YEAR, EmpHireDate) as 'Y', Count(empHireDate) as 'C' 
from Employee 
Where EmpProjID = 1 
group by EmpHireDate 
order by EmpHireDate asc  

select 'Q' + Q + '-' + Y as 'Quarter', Sum(C) over (order by DID) as 'Count' from EmpGrowth GROUP BY c,q,y,did Order by DID
```

[image: What I get compared to what I need]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are not aggregating correctly. Based on your attempt, I would recommend:

```
select y, q, concat('Q', q, '-', y) qtr, sum(count(*)) over(order by y, q) cnt 
from employee 
cross apply (values (datepart(quarter, EmpHireDate), datepart(year, EmpHireDate))) x(q, y)
where EmpProjID = 1 
group by y, q
order by y, q
```

Comment: Sorry... Lateral is not recognized by SQL Server. Is there something that can be used in it's place?

Comment: @JimBedson: my bad., the syntax is `cross apply`. Fixed.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Q' to data type int. Can't seem to correct this error. I'm guessing it's because I'm trying to concatenate the quarter and year into "Q3-2019". Do you know how I can get around that?